# PHP OAuth Class fetch using a proxy server

Tags: php, oauth, proxy

I've been looking through the threads and haven't been able to find anything...

I'm having a problem using the PHP OAuth class fetch method.

Currently doing this

```
$oauth->fetch($this->access_token_url, array('xoauth_oauth2_access_token' => $access_token), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
```

the problem is that we need to connect to the to the server via a proxy. And the URL argument only takes a string. I was looking at the OAUTH doc at https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.fetch.php and tried looking through some of the other methods, but didn't find anything. Is there a way I can build the connection up first or even just extend the class to work w/ a proxy?

Any help on this would be amazing, been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

thanks,
Brodie

Comment: You should extend the oauth class and rewrite the part were the connection is being made. You can simply use curl.

Comment: Hey john, I appreciate the response. Do you know where I can find documentation on extending the class? Or should I try to find the base code and edit it directly? Sorry not much experience extending php classes.